# How can I select a row plus all its related rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure:

```
// mytable
+----+---------+
| id | related |
+----+---------+
| 1  | NULL    |
| 2  | 1       |
+----+---------+
```

Now I need to select the row that has `id = 1` and all rows that have `related = 1`. Here is my query:

```
select m1.*
from mytable m1
left join mytable m2 on m1.id = m2.related
where m1.id = 1
```

But it returns just the first row. What's wrong?

Comment: A join is used to join two tables. I think you want inner join if you really do want to use a join.

Comment: Can you add expected output in your question section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 1 in (id, related);
```

No self-join is needed.

EDIT:

If you want performance, then write the query as:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where id = 1
union all
select t.*
from mytable t
where related = 1;
```

And define two indexes on `mytable(id)` and `mytable(related)`.

Comment: What kind of index does it need? `mytable(id, related)` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . `or` does not optimize well with indexes.  See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you are looking for this:

```
select m1.*
from mytable m1 where m1.id = 1 or m1.related = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use inner join.

```
select m1.*
from mytable m1
inner join mytable m2 on m1.id = m2.related
where m1.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try UNION ALL or if you don't want duplicates use UNION

```
select * from mytable m1 where m1.id = 1
UNION
select * from mytable m2 where m2.related = 1
```

Comment: You can try `union all`, or if you must also remove duplicates use `union`. *(`union` removes duplicates, not `union all`)*

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code

`SELECT * 
   FROM table
  WHERE (id = 1 AND related IS NULL) 
     OR related = 1;`

I create a table with more items and it returns what you want. Check this[image]